# How to get current request url in Sharepoint 2013 in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How to get current request url

I type in browser:

`http://srv-1/sites/1001/Account Documents/Order`

but in Page_Load in my controls I get

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url    = http://srv-1/_layouts/15/start.aspx`

and

`Page.Request.RawUrl = Page.Request.RawUrl`

I need to retrieve information: `/Account Documents/Order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of [Minimal Download Strategy](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds) feature. Your url is rewritten by SharePoint.

Easiest solution is to disable this feature, but you can also try to get url via [SPUtility.OriginalServerRelativeRequestUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.originalserverrelativerequesturl.aspx) property or refactor your code not use url, but current library or something else.

Comment: It still return only "srv-1/sites/1001/_layouts/15/start.aspx"; and I need also this: /Account Documents/Order

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does it’s own URL rewrites, if you would try that for example for the page

The solution is to use special property on [SPUtility class – SPUtility.OriginalServerRelativeRequestUrl][1]

http://blog.voyta.net/2012/07/09/how-to-get-original-request-url-in-sharepoint/

**This property returns the original URL before it was rewritten, which is useful if you need to get the subweb from which an application page was loaded.**

As this URL is server-relative, to get full url, you can use:

> SPUtility.GetFullUrl(SPContext.Current.Site,
>   SPUtility.OriginalServerRelativeRequestUrl);

This can be useful if you need to redirect for example to the same URL with some additional parameters.

Thanks

Comment: It still return only "http://srv-1/sites/1001/_layouts/15/start.aspx" and I need also this: /Account Documents/Order